# Avoiding multiple calls to ImportXML

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet that I'm using to monitor several YouTube videos.  For each video I am using ImportXML to grab the following data from individual YouTube video pages:

- Title
- Views
- Keywords

To be clear - I have no problem using ImportXML in this way.  This approach is working perfectly.  The problem is that each one of these individual pieces of data uses it's own ImportXML call.  This limits me to 16 videos since Google places a reasonable limitation of 50 calls per sheet.  3 datum * 16 videos = 48 calls, 2 less than the maximum.

What I think I'd like to do is make ONE call per video, grab the entire HTML, stuff it into a hidden cell, and PARSE THAT CELL for the data.  That'd permit me to grab 50 videos, which has much more appeal obviously.

I've got the plan, but no idea if I could parse a CELL using XPath that way.  The documentation I've seen doesn't appear to permit using XPath that way, but it seems so obvious.  Has anyone done this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple XPath expressions in a single importXML call.

You can have your functionality with either:

- Manipulate your URL - instead of calling the video page, you can call a specific search page. For example: `http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=<your-user-name>` and fetch each column with a specific XPath expression, once for all videos
- Have a more general XPath - extract all tags that contain your information and then filter the ones that you need.

Comment: Guy - great suggestions! I was thinking that I could somehow use ImportXML in each cell, but instead of referencing a URL, I could reference a CELL location which would have the data from an initial ImportXML call that actually referenced the URL.

This got me thinking - perhaps I could use the ImportXML call as designed, then use REGEX to parse the cell and fill the other cells with the information I need. Tried it, then ran into another limitation: google cells can only hold 4000 chars.  

I'm thinking that a PHP/JQuery/YouTubeAPI solution is in order. 

I'll explore your suggestions first.

Comment: The second proposal of getting many tags (all div/span/...) and then filter them with Regex, is avoiding the 4,000 chars limit.
You can also check out using Google Refine for such task as it is able to handle HTML parsing very nicely, and you can upload its output to a Google Spreadsheet.